# Can I resolve 'Could not find schema information for the ...' messages in VS for .template files?

Tags: visual-studio, rendering-template, e-commerce

I'm working on modifying a ProductDetails.template file using Visual Studio 2010, which ties into Commerce Server, I believe.

When I load this file I get Messages (as opposed to Warnings or Errors) like the following:

- Could not find schema information for the element 'template'.
- Could not find schema information for the element 'productProperties'.
- Could not find schema information for the element 'property'.

After 100 items Visual Studio stops trying.

I'm aware that I can simply hide messages, but I would hope that there's some way to correct this, instead of merely hiding it.

Normally I would associate a schema with the XML file to correct this, but in this case I'd rather not screw with the file, since I'm not sure of what this would break.

Unfortunately, that seems to be the only solution I'm finding after searching.

Is there any way to correct these messages in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the .xsd file which validates the content of the .template file, you can go to property of the file (F4) and specify the location of .xsd file. That will help VS.NET validate the file and provide intellisense as you edit the file, it will not modify the file itself.

.xsd files are generally installed in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Xml\Schemas when you install development tools or SDK of the product.